# Font changes after sent on Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-office-2010

I have a user that sends mails with default font Arial size 10 but when the mail is sent it changes automatically to Calibri size 14

So the user is typing with Arial 10 but when it's sent it's Calibri 14

TS Steps:
1. This happens with New mail/Reply/Reply all/Forward
2. Checked the Fonts and Stationary and it's on default
3. Checked the Format Text and made sure it's on default (HTML)
4. Created a new outlook profile
5. Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features and repaired MS Office
6. Changed the font in Fonts and Stationary and restarted the outlook and it worked with a different font but when I set it back to default (Arial) it still sends with Calibri 14
7. Windows has the latest update

Windows 7
Version 6.1
Build 7601 SP1
Outlook 2010 Version: 14.0.7128.5000

Answer (score 0):

If you send emails via the web mail, will same issue occur?

We can also check messages in Sent Item folder to see if font display correctly.

What if we change format to Plain Text?

We can try opening Outlook in safe mode to see if the issue continues. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter. This helps eliminate whether the problem lies on any third party add-ins.

If issue continues, we can rename NormalEmail.dotm file which is used in Outlook to support the new email editor. To do this, please check steps below:

1. The file is normally located in the following location:
   C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
2. Rename it to .old.
3. Restart Outlook.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply

1. I have renamed Normal.dotm and NormalEmail.dotm to .old but it didn't work  2. I have tried webmail and Safe mode and both worked fine and the font didn't change from Arial  3. I checked the Add-ins but didn't find anything strange or more than normal  4. Tried to send to multiple users but the same result Calibri 14

Comment: If it works under safe mode, we can unselect all add-ins in Outlook to test the results.

Comment: I have found out the Format text is the problem, after changing it to Rich Text it works fine and if I set it back to HTML it gives the same result. Now I am confused how to edit HTML format text in outlook!!?

Comment: Can you reproduce this on the web mail?

Comment: It works fine on webmail and Safe mode, tried it in normal mode and it worked fine with RichText format but not with HTML format

Comment: Have you un-selected add-ins in outlook one by one to test the result? If issue persists after disabling all add-ins, we can also temporarily close anti-virus software to see if this issue was caused by their integration with Outlook client.

Comment: I have only compared the add-ins in the outlook with another working PCs in the company and there was no difference.